# ADD ROUTE command in windows 2008R2

Tags: windows-server-2008, vpn, routing

I don't know much about Networking, So excuse me if I am raising some basic issues.
I have a LAN where there is a Windows Server 2008R2 with some clients connected to it. The clients are not joined to the domain of the Server (they are in a WORKGROUP). I have set up a VPS on the server machine (PPTP) with a Static address pool of range `10.0.0.1` -> `10.0.0.10` but the LAN range itself is `192.168.1.1` -> `192.168.1.254`. When I connect to the server from another location over the internet, I can just see the server and I can not see the other clients which are in the same LAN as the server. what to do to see the other clients?
a friend of mine said that you should use the ADD ROUTE command. Beacuse of that I used this command as my title. What would be the best way to address this problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I could solve that.
I did as following:
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Did you enable LAN Routing when you configured RRAS on the server? If not, you need to. Without LAN Routing enabled, VPN clients will only have access to the server but noth the LAN that the server is connected to.

Comment: I have enabled `VPN ACCESS` and `LAN Routing` as you said. What to do next?

Comment: Try connecting to or accessing a share on one of the other machines.

Comment: I did that but I still have the problem. I can not connect to the other clients with their Local IP (192.168.1.1 -> 192.168.1.254). I can just connect to the server with the IP 10.0.0.1